# Switch camera between front and rear functionality in react js using Agora-RTC-SDK ng

Tags: javascript, reactjs, agora.io, agora

I want to implement swtiching camera functionality inside my live stream project. so user can  change camera accordingly. Using Agora-RTC-SDK ng, when I try to change camera in mobile browser it did't provide me new device id and did't change the camera. if any body can help me please provide me solution.
Thanks